# JQueryMobile Slider widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm inserting the sliders with jQuery but then the style of jQueryMobile is not added...
Here's the html code:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h3>Compra de productos por colores y paquetes</h3>
            <div id='insert_colors_slider'></div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the Javascript part to insert dynamically the sliders. They don't have the style of jquerymobile when added dynamically...

```
var array_colors_available = (product_info.pcolors).split(',');
    array_colors_available.forEach(function printSliderEachColor(element, index, array){
        $('#insert_colors_slider').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> <label for="slider1">'+element+' : '+'</label><input id='+element+' type="range" name="slider" value="0" min="0" max="25" data-highlight="false"data-track-theme="a"></fieldset></div>');
    });
    $('#insert_colors_slider').collapsible();
```

Comment: I understand you are trying to do something with jQuery mobile sliders. But what exactly is it you are trying to achieve? Your question is a bit vague and I am not really sure what your problem is. Any extra detail would be appreciated.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck What happens is that when i insert dynamically sliders, they don't have the style (CSS) of jQueryMobile theme and i want to have the style.